# Angular 11 how to map data from firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from Firestore, to display in an edit component template. I'm getting an error that " Type 'Observable ' is missing the following properties from type 'Agency': agencyId, benefitCardName, benefitCardPhotoUrl, logoUrl, and 3 more."
my component:

```
    agency$: Agency;

this.agency$  = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(switchMap(params => this.afs.collection<Agency>('agencies').doc<Agency>(`${params.get('agencyId')}`)
      .valueChanges().pipe(map( (data: Agency) =>
    {
      this.name = data.name,
      this.phone = data.phone;
    }))));
  console.log(this.agency$);
```

my interface

```
export interface Agency {
  agencyId: Promise<string>;
  benefitCardName: string;
  benefitCardPhotoUrl: Promise<string>;
  logoUrl: Promise<string>;
  name: string;
  phone: string;
  pocTimesheetRequired: boolean;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would define the observable type, this should do the job:

```
this.afs.collection<Agency[]>('agencies').doc<Agency>(this.agencyId).valueChanges();
```

> If this does not solve your problem can you post how you use the observable?

Comment: I changed my function slightly, and I also added the type like you suggested @Norbert Bartko, but I'm still getting the same error. At this point, I'm only doing console.log to see what my object looks like, before I'm ready to interpolate. If I change the my agency to this type: agency$: Observable<void>;, I get an anonymous subject but it's obviously not mapped correctly. All I see is the correct agencyID

Answer (score 0):

IN the end, I made quite a few change

```
agency$: Observable<Agency> = this.afs.collection<Agency | any>('agencies').doc(this.agencyId)
    .valueChanges().pipe(tap(console.log),
      map( (agency: Agency) => {
        // agency
          // .map(data => {
        const logoUrl = this.afStorage.storage.refFromURL('').child(`/thumbnails/${this.agencyId}_700x100.png`)
          .getDownloadURL();
        const benefitCardPhotoUrl = this.afStorage.storage.refFromURL('').child(`/${this.agencyId}_200x200.png`)
          .getDownloadURL();
        this.logoUrl = logoUrl;
        this.benefitCardPhotoUrl = benefitCardPhotoUrl;
        return agency;
})
);
```